# Why are there only two committers for the Blender documentation proposal?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that even though there is a vibrant Blender Stack Exchange community, there are still only two committers on the [SE Blender docs](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/blender). Why are there not more? Is it just because no one knows?

I know it isn't a replacement for the main manual, but the Stack Exchange documentation project is a very useful, unique method; I think it would definitely be a benefit. Please go commit to it, so that it can be started!

---

## Current Progress:

> ### 2 / 5

---

## 5 Committers:

> - **gandolf3**
> - **pycoder**
> - **?**
> - **?**
> - **?**

Comment: I wasn't quite aware of this tbh but stackoverflow is not the place to document Blender IMO. If i'm missing something in the details please correct me.

Comment: @iKlsR I disagree. SO has a [tag:blender] tag and code-oriented blender questions (python scripting) are on-topic there. Why shouldn't at least some scripting-oriented blender docs/examples be on-topic? That said, it doesn't seem like scope is all that strict. There's a [vim documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vim), and even a [vlc proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vlc). Plus, participating in the beta shows enthusiasm on the part of non-SO sites, which should encourage them to expand SE documentation to such sites when the time comes.

Comment: @iKlsR It is a different type of manual...take a look at some of the other ones, and I think you will see how useful it can be. It should be on the general SE website or BSE in my opinion, but wherever it is, I think that it will be a help because it allows for easy information reuse. Someone can write an answer there, then link to it in the context of other answers so as not to have to write the same thing all that often. Another idea behind the documentation is that it is frequently edited by everyone, and so just about everything that gets voted up goes through many edits.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation/

Answer (score 2):

I knew about it from day one. I was even very active with the documentation project on that first day. However I quickly got a distaste for it, there are and were problems with the system.

Personally I don't want blender docs on SO. I don't like the documentation system, and aside from coding questions **blender is off topic on SO**.
I'm sure not going to stand in the way of the blender tag getting its own docs there, but I am not going to commit to writing the docs. The more blender knowledge the better, I guess.

Yet, if there is this much of a struggle just to get 5 people to commit to starting the documentation (gandalf3 brought this very thing up over **three** months ago), I wonder how good it will be. The last thing we need is another so-so repository of half done blender knowledge.

So to answer your question, yes I knew about it, but the reason I have not committed (aside from needing more rep in the blender tag on SO even to be able to commit) is because I don't want to.

Comment: Fair enough, I won't argue about if blender is off topic or not on SO...

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation/